# Help a Noob Debug Some Code

Tags: solidity, remix

Hello Eth Stack Exchange,

I am practicing Solidity on Remix. This is actually the first language I have ever learned. In the contract below, I created a program to allow users to create dinosaurs and then fight them against one another.

I wanted to make the results of the fights (semi)random and in favor of the attacker, I tried to do that via this line of code in the fightDino function:  **if (uint((keccak256(now)) % 100) > 40)** {

Why is the compiler telling me "Operator % not compatible with types bytes32 and int_const 100"

Here is a copy of the whole contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract DinoFighter {

uint cooldownTime = 30 seconds;

struct Dino {
    string name;
    string color;
    uint readyTime;
    uint level;
    string status;
}

Dino[] public dinos;
mapping (uint => address) public dinoToOwner;

 modifier onlyOwner(uint _dinoId) {
     require(dinoToOwner[_dinoId] == msg.sender);
     _;
 }

function createDino(string _name, string _color) public {
    uint id = dinos.push(Dino("Velonica", "Brown", (now + cooldownTime), 0, "none")) - 1;
    dinoToOwner[id] = msg.sender;
}

function fightDino(uint _dinoId, uint _targetId) public onlyOwner(_dinoId) returns (string) {
    Dino storage myDino = dinos[_dinoId];
    Dino storage tDino = dinos[_targetId];
    if (uint((keccak256(now)) % 100) > 40) {
        myDino.level++;
        myDino.status = "king";
        tDino.readyTime = now + cooldownTime;
        tDino.status = "loser";
        return "Winner";
    } 
    else {
        tDino.level++;
        tDino.status = "king";
        myDino.readyTime = now + cooldownTime;
        myDino.status = "loser";
        return "Loser";
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you're getting pertains to the usage of operand `%`. Change the bracket ordering in the `if` conditional as follows and you won't get the error.

```
if ((uint(keccak256(now)) % 100) > 40) {
    myDino.level++;
    ...
}
```

The error ***"Operator % not compatible with types bytes32 and int_const 100"*** is thrown because the operand resolution for `%` in your code happens such that the mode of the return value from `keccak256(now)` is calculated against `100`, but since `keccak256` returns `bytes32` type, the compiler throws the error that it can't use `%` with a `byte32` type and a `const 100` type. I fixed it by converting the return value of `keccak256(now)` to an `uint` and then everything works fine.

Comment: @JulianMartinez glad I could help :) You can accept the answer by clicking the tick button next to the answer.